# Is it possible to enable more drive letters than A-Z in explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, mount

I have a lot of partitions and drives, and I would like to be able to mount more, but I ran out of letters and now the drives are being mounted over the network drives. When I try to open a network drive, it loads a local drive that is mounted after all letters were taken instead which must be a bug. I have drives mounted further under things like [:\ 1:\ 2:\ and so on, and I can access them from the command line, but they don't show in Explorer and I seemingly cannot open these from Explorer in any way.

Is it possible to modify Explorer or do something to allow it to show and open other drive letters than just A-Z?